# Is it possible for Javascript running on a web page to connect to a remote server?

Tags: javascript, networking

For example if I wanted to make Javascript communicate with a server coded in C++ using TCP.

Comment: You're looking for AJAX or web sockets.

Comment: use socket.io javascript library

Comment: Is the response a JSON object?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can send HTTP requests to a server using AJAX and the [XmlHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) object. As pointed out in the comments you could also use websockets, but the server-side implementation would be more compilcated.

It isn't possible to send arbitrary TCP packets to a server from JavaScript.

Comment: it is used for http not for tcp

Comment: @kishan http uses TCP (it runs on top of it)

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX inside the java-script and hit the requested service on the Server